# Setup a $watch to a return value of a service's function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

**TL;DR** How can I setup, in a controller, a `$watch` to a DI'ed service's function return value?

My app has a service in order to make it easy to share data between controllers. I'm trying to setup a `$watch` to one of those variables from a controller. However, I wanted to access through the service's getter for that particular variable.

This is the code in the controller

```
    //this is the controller
    var vm = this;
    vm.isValidPhase = false;

    activate();

    ////////////////

    function activate() {
        vm.isValidPhase = userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity();

        $scope.$watch('userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity()',
                     function(newValue) {
            vm.isValidPhase = newValue;
        });
    }
```

And in the `userProgressService` I have:

```
   //this is the service
   var current = {
        phaseNumber : 0,
        phaseValidity : false,
        phase   : {},
        userInput   : {}
    };

    // ... ... ...

    var exports = {
        getCurrentPhaseData  : getCurrentPhaseData,
        getCurrentPhaseValidity : getCurrentPhaseValidity,
        setCurrentPhaseValidity : setCurrentPhaseValidity,
        getExistingUserInput : getExistingUserInput
    };

    return exports;

    // ... ... ...

    function getCurrentPhaseValidity() {
        return current.phaseValidity;
    }

    // ... ... ...
```

In my unit tests to the controller using *mocha, bard, chai* and *sinon*, I'm doing:

```
describe('initial state', function () {
    it('should be an invalid phase', function () {
        expect(userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity(),
               'in service function').to.be.false;
        expect(controller.isValidPhase,
               'in controller scope').to.be.false;
    });
});
```

And I'm getting an error on the second assertion:

`AssertionError: in controller scope: expected undefined to be false`

Now, from playing with commenting and uncommenting, I've noticed that the problem comes from the `$watch` expression in the controller. But I don't know what is the problem with it... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use a watch? Just don't store the result in a variable. Call the service method everytime you need the value.

Comment: In the case I want it for, I really need to watch the value. Basically, I want to change a button's "availability" based on that variable's value

Comment: So, expose the function of the service in the scope (i.e. `$scope.getCurrentPhaseValidity = userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity;`), and use `<button ng-show="getCurrentPhaseValidity()">`

Comment: hum... didn't think of that one...

Comment: Yup! that worked! Thanks a lot @JBNizet

Comment: Just so that you're not frustrated, your watched expression is incorrect, because there is no `userProgressService` variable on the scope. The correct way to watch what this function returns would be to pass the function itself to $watch: `$scope.$watch(userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity, ...)`

Comment: Thanks man! if you want, you can answer the question, I'll mark it as the correct one

Comment: Don't worry about that. I have more than enough points. I'm happy you learnt something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments @JBNizet pointed out that the `$watch` expression is wrong, instead, I should be watching the function itself, since the service is not defined in the `$scope`. However, he also made me realize that, at least for this case, I didn't need to setup that `$watch`. In his own words

> [...] expose the function of the service in the scope (i.e.
>   `$scope.getCurrentPhaseValidity =
>   userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity;`), and use `<button
>   ng-show="getCurrentPhaseValidity()">`

I did as he told and changed the controller scope to

```
//... controller ...
vm.isValidPhase = userProgressService.getCurrentPhaseValidity;
```

Now I can use `ng-show` and alike with `isValidPhase` in the HTML under the controller.

As expected, it worked and fitted the purpose for which I wanted to watch the variable, which was to activate/deactivate a button based on its value.

For what I can think of, this solution covers much of whatever related problems you'd have with this.